# Adding Richfaces to Eclipse Palette?

Tags: eclipse, richfaces, palette

I am using Eclipse 3.6, and want to add Richfaces to Palette.Could anyone give source or explain how to do please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://labs.jboss.com/tools/

there you go :)